# Floating icon over a link does not receive mouse click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display an icon floating over the right side of a link when the mouse is over the link. The idea is to be able to click on the icon to display a dialog. This works as long as no link text is under the icon. If the text is so long that the icon is over the text then the link is executed. The icon click handler is never called.

What can I do to give the icon priority over the link? Is this a problem because the icon is floating?

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| This is the link                                |ICON|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="group-content ui-sortable">
    <a title="GMail|http://mail.google.com/mail" class="link show-option " 
            href="http://mail.google.com/mail" target="GOOGLE">
        <span title="link.openSettings" class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear link-settings" 
            style="display: none; z-index: 9999;"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon link-icon ui-icon-link ui-sortable-handle"></span>
        GMail
    </a>
    ... more links ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.link-settings {
    padding: 2px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    float: right;
    z-index: 9999;   /** bring to the top ... */
}
```

JavaScript: (called when page initialised. adds a popup icon over all links)

```
$('.link')
    .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear link-settings'></span>")
    .hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find(".link-settings")
                .show()
                .css('z-index', '9999');
        },
        function () { $(this).find(".link-settings").hide(); }
    )
    .click(function () {
        console.log("Link clicked");
    })
;
```

Answer (score 1):

The span is **inside** the link..so of course the link works..you're still clicking it.

You would need to have the span *outside* the link and positioned on top of the link.

I don't know your full HTML & CSS you have in place but essentially you need to wrap the link and span something like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
a {
  display: block;
  background: plum;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .25em;
  color: red;
}
.link-settings {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .25em;
  display: none;
}
.wrap:hover .link-settings {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>
  <span class="link-settings">Icon</span>
</<div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. You say 'of course the link works' but it did surprise me that a contained item which has a click handler did not get priority over the link which surely lies below the span in the z-index. Just for fun I changed the <span> to a <a> and the containing <a> still has priority.